# Re-use same local port number with Netty client

Tags: java, netty

I have developed a java TCP client with Netty.
I should use the same local port number to connect to the server if I disconnects but I can't use same localport. I think the reason is the socket is in TIME_WAIT state after closing the connection and kernel doesn`t let it.

Is there a to use always same localport number to connect to a TCP server?

Comment: You should use the same local port number why? This exposes you to a number of difficulties, starting with the necessity for a `bind()` before you `connect()`, but also the limitation that you have to wait 1*MSL between successive connections from the same client host, and also that no client host can have concurrent connections to the server.o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)`.

Sample code:

```
private Bootstrap createBootstrap(ConnectionConfig config) {
    final int THREAD_NUM = 1;
    Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup(THREAD_NUM);

    bootstrap.group(group)
            .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
            .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
            .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
                    ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();
                    pipeline.addLast(new IdleStateHandler(config.getReaderIdleTimeMs(), config.getWriterIdleTimeMs(), 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                    pipeline.addLast(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(Integer.MAX_VALUE, PacketProtocol.Offset.LENGTH, PacketProtocol.LENGTH_LEN, 0-PacketProtocol.LENGTH_LEN, 0));
                    pipeline.addLast(new CodecHandler());
                    pipeline.addLast(new NettyChannelHandler(ConnectionImpl.this));
                }
            });
    try {
        bootstrap.bind(localPort).sync();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LOG.error("bootstrap bind localPort={} error", localPort, e);
        throw new IllegalStateException("bootstrap bind error");
    }
    return bootstrap;
}
```

Comment: True but risky. The TIME_WAIT state is there for a good reason: to ensure that successive connections can't get mixed up.